# Does the order you collect the Dark Moon Trigon and Light Moon Trigon affect the game in any way?

Tags: sword-and-sworcery

In Superbrothers' Sword and Sworcery it appears you can collect the Light Moon and Dark Moon trigons in any order.

Does this affect the story in any way?

Comment: There is one achievement if you collect the dark one last, not the other way round.